# Grabbing the value of a specific JSON object key in SQL

Tags: sql, json

I have a column called `cred` in my database that stores JSON:

`{"schema":"schema_name","other_key":"other_value"}`

I am trying to do return rows that would contain a column called "schema" which would have a value of `schema_name`. We are using an older version of MySQL which doesn't have the latest JSON tools and I am wondering how I could extract this information into its own column.

Current query I've been trying is:

```
SELECT c.clientId, c.feePercent, c.absorbCharges, c.cred FROM clients c
WHERE active = 1
AND `c.dbCred.key`='schema'
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using? For Postgresql use https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html, for mysql use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/json-functions.html

Comment: I think it's MariaDB 5.4 but will need to check

Comment: MySql 5.5.5-10.0.17 Maria DB

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_extract` function of [MariaDB json Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-functions/).
Example:

```
SELECT c.clientId, c.feePercent, c.absorbCharges, c.cred FROM clients c
WHERE active = 1
AND json_extract(c.dbCred, '$[key]')='value'
```

Comment: This gives me an error:

FUNCTION bs_admin.json_extract does not exist

Comment: bs_admin is the table name